# Find the coordinates of $(-3,0,2)$ with respect to a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the coordinates of $(-3,0,2)$ with respect to a basis ${v1,v2,v3}.

I was given:
$$v_1=(1,0,1),
v_2=(-1,2,1),
v_3=(0,1,-1).$$

I already showed that $\{v1,v2,v3\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^3$ (they are linearly independant). I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thanks for any help/advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i row reduced $$\pmatrix{1&-1&0&-3\\0&2&1&0\\1&1&-1&2} \to \pmatrix{1&0&0&-1.75\\0&1&0&1.25\\0&0&1&-2.5} $$ so that $$(3,0,-2) = -1.75v_1+1.25v_2 -2.5v_3$$

Comment: @Bye_World, what exactly is that you edited?

Comment: The last line of your second matrix was $(0,0,0,-2.5)$.

Comment: thanks! that was just what I needed to get me started.

Comment: @knames, you are welcome.